# product_type_options get saved value

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have an issue with a product type option checkbox.
The value is saved correctly in the database.
If the value is yes the checkbox is unchecked.

The code that I wrote below

```
<?php
function add_octopus_child_option( $product_type_options ) {
    $product_type_options['_childocto'] = array(
        'id'            => '_childocto',
        'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_octopus',
        'label'         => __( 'Gekoppeld', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Vink dit aan indien dit niet het hoofdproduct is.', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    return $product_type_options;
}
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'add_octopus_child_option' );

function save_product_data_octopus($post_id){
    $woocommerce_checkbox = isset( $_POST['_childocto'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_childocto', $woocommerce_checkbox );
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_product_data_octopus');
?>
```

Who can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code please check the below code.

```
 function add_octopus_child_option( $product_type_options ) {
    $product_type_options['childocto'] = array(
      'id'            => '_childocto',
      'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_octopus',
      'label'         => __( 'Gekoppeld', 'woocommerce' ),
      'description'   => __( 'Vink dit aan indien dit niet het hoofdproduct is.', 'woocommerce' ),
      'default'       => 'no'
   );
   return $product_type_options;
 } 
 add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'add_octopus_child_option' );

 function save_product_data_octopus($post_id){
    $woocommerce_checkbox = isset( $_POST['_childocto'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_childocto', $woocommerce_checkbox );
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple','save_product_data_octopus'  );
 add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_variable', 'save_product_data_octopus'  );
```

Try with the above code and if does not work let me know.

Comment: Can you please explain the modifications? Is it just the two add_actions at the bottom instead of save_post? What do those hooks do?

Comment: You creating a custom checkbox as a product type in woo-commerce so I have just used woo-commerce hook for the simple product and variable products because those hook working for the products type meta so.

Comment: Hi Hims V the code does not work. What I said the value is saved in the database but the issue is on the read side. The checkbox does not follow the value from the database.

Comment: Hi Ben Please see my updated code, i have just remove _from the $product_type_options['childocto']  value, and it's works.